Issues Synchronizing Real-Time Favorite Status Updates in a React App with Delayed/out of sync API Responses
In a React app for work, I need to implement a favorites feature for card items. Our data comes from a Portal with its own UI and favoriting capability, but the API doesn't include an isFavorite property in our data items. To determine favorites, I make a secondary call to retrieve favorited item IDs and cross-check them with our item list on app load.
When I toggle the favorite status on an item, it works as I can see the change in the Portal. However, the issue is that when I immediately requery the favorited IDs to update the UI, the API returns the old list. The list of favorite Id’s isn't reflected immediately. Using a setTimeout helps, but it takes a few seconds to get the correct list, making it unreliable.
I attempted an optimistic update from scratch, but it still doesn't prevent the API from returning the outdated list of favorite Id’s thus rendering the star icon status unreliable.
How can I maintain accurate and timely updates to the favorite status in my React app, considering the API's occasional delay in reflecting changes?

I doubt there's a lot you can do without fixing the API to become reliable. How could you distinguish an outdated response from a proper one?

circling back here I ended up relying on http status from data call to determine ui updates ¯_(ツ)_/¯
